# Laravel form submission randomly stops working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, server

I am currently having a weird problem with my laravel application. At random points, my form submission will stop working on all my forms. I check in Chrome developer tools and follow the network activity and it seems to go through everything correctly but instead of submitting my form, it just seems to refresh the page. If I have validation errors made on purpose, they are not displayed anywhere. If everything is correct, it just reloads the form empty. It only happens on forms, my Ajax requests work.

It happened to me a week ago for the first time after I uploaded a live version of my application to the server I'm working on for people to use. Came back the next day to realize everything was working as it should without me changing anything.

It is now happening again, this time on the dev version that I'm the only one using. None of my forms will submit, just refreshing the page instead. I can absolutely not figure out what is causing this and why it seems to happen and solve itself randomly and it's driving me crazy since I can pretty much not do anything while it's doing this.

Has anything similar happened to anyone that could help me solve it or does anyone know why this could be happening?

Here is some code from one of my requests where I do my validation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class JobRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'project_name' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'end_time' => array('required', 'regex:/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/'),
            'delivery_date' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'delivery_time' => array('required', 'regex:/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/'),
            'advisor.0'  => 'min:1',
            'advisor.1'  => 'different:advisor.0',
            'job_type' => 'min:1',
            'text_other_job_type' => 'required_if:other_job_type,1',
            'project_desc' => 'required',
            'name_client' => 'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the opening of my form and the submit buttons:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['JobController@store'], 'id' => 'add_project', 'method' => 'post', 'name' => 'add_project', 'files'=>true])!!}
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_job" value=0>
            @include('pages.job.form', ['isEdit' => false])
            <div class="">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-7 btn_group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default arrow_link_right" value="store" name="store">{{ trans('add_job.submit') }}<span ></span></button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_project.action='{{URL::route('storeTemplate')}}'; return true;" value="template" name="templateSub" formnovalidate>{{ trans('add_job.saveTemplate') }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="reset_form('add_project');" >{{ trans('add_job.reset') }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Do you use CSRF token?

Comment: I have no experience with Laravel, and you've not provided any code or what you've tried (which you should), but I'd recommend taking a look at what data is being submitted. It could be the case that there is invalid information, so the entire submission is just being ignored.

Comment: Which version of Laravel? Can you post your validation code?

Comment: @Mantas Yes I use CSRF token and the default check for laravel

Comment: @jhmckimm I didn't think it useful to post code since it happens on all forms, even those that have been working for a long time and I haven't made any changes on in a while. And it just happens whenever I try to submit any data, valid or not

Comment: @rouquinsman It most certainly would help to get some code to show. As I'm reading it I'm thinking of a few things it could be but I am not going to write the 20 different things it could be without at least seeing a basic implementation. For example - if the forms are not being sent via JS will they work?

Comment: @RogerCreasy Version 5.2.44. I'll post a snippet of my validation code as an edit in my question in a moment.

Comment: Could we also see your JavaScript code? I'm 90% sure that this is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are catching possible errors and that your routes are within the "web" middleware?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. I had followed the instructions in this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-returns-null-in-laravel-52 but instead of moving the middlewares out of the web group, I had copied them, which caused my problem. Moving them instead of copying them fixed it. Thank you all for trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know you have solved it. Would you add an answer in that respect below?

Answer (score 0):

1. When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
   stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
   application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
   GO -config/app.php line num 29

   'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', enable),

it will help to see what happend code on browser.

make sure add POST route on routes.php

```
Route::post('url','JobController@store');
```

check you Ajax post is ok

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    data: {data}
    success: function( data ) {

    }
});
```

some time is happen, missing token while post data. add token on each ajax call with data which is posting

```
 data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),other data},
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late for reply but still can help someone. I was having same problem. I had resource controllers that were registered inside admin prefix while it's store method was being used outside of group prefix for form submission which was causing this weird behaviour. I simply added except('store') method to resource and now it is working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).